# Form not Posting in Django

Tags: django, forms, authentication, post

I'm trying to do some pretty basic form posts with Django, but whenever I try to click on the button to submit the information nothing happens.  No errors or messages of any kind show up in terminal or in developer in Chrome.  There is no JS on this page just straight html:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
    <input type="text" id="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="button" value="Sign Up!"/>
</form>
```

My view for this page is pretty straightforward as well:

```
def sign_up(request):
    return render_to_response('portal/signup.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I'm really baffled as to what is going on, I've been following [this](http://neverfear.org/blog/view/97/User_Authentication_With_Django) to learn authentication.  Everything works but I thought adding a "create user" would be a next step.  I can't seem to get any form of any kind to work on other pages as well.

Any help would be great, I'm going crazy!

Comment: Are you sure you want `action="/"` instead of `action=""`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you're using

```
<input type="button" value="Sign Up!"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up!"/>
```

the input submit will send all the form data to the server, the input button won't.
You can learn a little bit more about forms here : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp