# request.FILES always empty on file upload

Tags: html, django, forms, file, django-forms

I am totally stumped on this, and must be doing something incredibly stupid. I am trying to simply upload a file on a Django project. The problem seems to be that NO form data is getting passed through to the server--only the csrf token. I am running Django 1.5.1, python 2.7, virtualenv, on a Mac, and using the built-in Django development server.

My HTML form is:

```
{% load url from future %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'showreport' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Upload grade csv file: </label>
    <input type="hidden" id="testing" value="maybe" />
    <input type="file" id="grade_csv" />
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" />
</form>
```

My model:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
file = models.FileField(upload_to='/media/', blank=True, null=True)
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Document

class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
"""
to handle uploading grades csv file
"""
class Meta:
    models = Document
```

My views.py:

```
def report(request):
"""
Process the CSV file to remove inactive students
Manipulate to get right JSON format
Chart the results
"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm( request.POST, request.FILES )
    if form.is_valid():
        newfile = Document( file = request.FILES['file'] )
        newfile.save()

        classdata = {}
        studentdata = {}

        return render( request, 'report/showreport.html', { 'classdata': classdata, 'studentdata': studentdata } )
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()

return render( request, 'report/index.html', { 'form': form })
```

I have spent several hours searching for a solution, but nothing seems to work. [I have the enctype set correctly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) (I think), [I am using input type 'submit' for the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509308/form-not-posting-in-django), and [I am binding the form data to my model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) (doesn't matter, since request.FILES is empty). I also tried using a direct url in my form action (action='/report/showreport/') per [this Django newbie page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes), but that didn't make a difference. As far as I can tell, there are no other scripts binding to the form submit action and overriding the default action.

I also realize that the code above should most likley be request.FILES['grades_csv'] to match the form's input id...yet that also doesn't matter yet, since request.FILES is empty.

In trying to debug, I have set a pdb trace right before the if request.method == "POST" in my view. Using the console, I can see that my request.POST does not include my hidden "testing" input, and that request.FILES is empty. When I run this in a browser, it just returns me to my form page, essentially saying my form is invalid. My pdb results are here:

```
(Pdb) request.FILES
(Pdb) <MultiValueDict: {}>
(Pdb) request.POST['testing']
(Pdb) *** MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'testing' not found in <QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'0tGCChxa3Po619dCi114Sb9jmWRt82aj']}>"
(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'0tGCChxa3Po619dCi114Sb9jmWRt82aj']}>
```

If I try to access request.FILES in my views.py without checking if the form is valid, I get this error:

```
"Key 'file' not found in <MultiValueDict: {}>"
```

I am stumped and appreciate any help on why I cannot get this to work--it seems like it should be simple. I can manually create and write to files within my project directory using pdb, so I don't think permissions are the problem...the problem is in the form?

Comment: Looks like your html form is missing the name attributes in your input fields, try like <input type="file" id="grade_csv" name="file"/>

Comment: A few things that are suspicious to me. Your form inputs are missing `name` attributes. You are sub-classing `forms.Form` but have a `Meta` class indicating you want `forms.ModelForm`. If you intend to use a model form you don't need to instantiate a Document object because the form does this for you.

Comment: Genius--thanks! I'd be happy to accept as the answer if you submit it as one...

Comment: It's almost certainly the missing `name` attributes.  That's where the keys for the POST data come from, not the IDs.

Comment: name attributes fixed it...not sure I understand completely Scott's comment about model forms (I was trying to follow the [Django example on forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)). Does that mean I don't need the class Meta: tag?

Comment: You've declared your form as a subclass of the generic, non-model form class `forms.Form`.  Note that in the example, `ArticleForm` is a subclass of `ModelForm` rather than `Form` - `ModelForm` is a subclass of `Form` that provides a lot of useful features, including the ability to create the model instance when you save the validated form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope that you have already solved this issue.
I had the exactly same issue and I found out I had no name prop in input tag

`<input type="file" id="grade_csv" />` that is your input.

if it doesn't have name, django won't take it.
So add name prop then it will work well.

Answer (score 30):

Check that you have added `enctype` property into `form` tag.

Example from [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form):
`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/">`

Comment: Perfect solution. enctype="multipart/form-data" did the trick for me. Really Helpful . Thanks @Kuznetsov

Comment: You should consider making your answer a more encompassing one -> `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/foo/"><input type="file" name="grade_csv" /></form>`. Though there are only 5 upvotes for the answer below you, its both the accepted answer and an error that is probably encountered by a few 1000 people, and both are easy mistakes to be made.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too and was puzzling over it for a while. My error was the same -- that I was missing necessary fields on the `input` field.

In order to see what the actually required fields are, a very nice thing to do is, in this case:

```
from base.forms import DocumentForm ## or put whatever the name is of the app, which is unspecified in the question
print DocumentForm()
```

This will print the html that you need, including all the tags that this object requires. Very neat functionality which I missed the first time, but which is outlined in [the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Two things to make sure of here:

1. Form tag should contain attribute **"enctype="multipart/form-data"**
2. Each file field should have a **"name"** attribute

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="file" id="grade_csv" name="name" />
```

You have to add *name* to your input field.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a weird bug where it *shows* as empty when I print it out:

```
print(request.FILES)
# Prints <MultiValueDict: {}>
```

If I load up a debugger and actually inspect the object though, it's not empty and contains the data I was expecting. This is the same exact object in both cases. The debugger shows `FILES` as populated, then when I continue, `print` shows it as empty.

So, if you're like me and you wanted to poke at the object first to understand it a bit, maybe don't rely on `MultiValueDict`'s string representation. I can't explain the source of the bug though since `MultiValueDict` is just subclass of `dict` and uses `dict`'s `__str__`.